# How to handle Diagonal Gestures in android?

Tags: android, gesture-recognition, diagonal

I am facing a problem to calculate the diagonal swipe events in the android view.
Can any one give me some logic to identify the Diagonal gestures.
My Requirement is: Once the user swipe diagonally on the phone i need to trigger different events.
Like:
1) TopLeftToBottomRight.
2) TopRightToBottomLeft.
3) BottomLeftToTopRight.
4) BottomRightToTopLeft.

Please,Can any one have some logic to handle all these.
Sample application will be appreciated. Help me out of this i need to complete this task ASAP.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `GestureDectector` to recognize touch events and motion events. You will get the initial and final co-ordinates of the screen. You will then have to invoke an algorithm to determine the direction of your swipe gesture based on the co-ordinates that you get. It's not that difficult. Here's [a link](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/use-androids-gesture-detector-to-translate-a-swipe-into-an-event/1577) on how to use `GestureDetector`.

Here's a sample for recognizing left and right swipe and touch events:

You can improve upon this code in the method `onFling` to make it work your way.

```
package com.ex.gessture;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class GestureListenerActivity extends Activity {

FrameLayout frame;
GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
String TAG = "GestureListenerActivity";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    frame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame);

    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, mGestureListener);

    frame.setOnTouchListener(new FrameLayout.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Gesture Event Handler
 */
private SimpleOnGestureListener mGestureListener = new SimpleOnGestureListener() {

    int swipe_Min_Distance = 100;
    int swipe_Max_Distance = 350;
    int swipe_Min_Velocity = 100;
/*      
    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.i(TAG, "[CALLBACK_GL] boolean onDown(e:" + e + ")");
        return super.onDown(e);
    }
*/
    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e)
    {

        /**
         *
         * Do your stuff
         *
         */

        return super.onSingleTapUp(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.i(TAG, "[CALLBACK_GL] boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(e:" + e + ")");
        return super.onSingleTapConfirmed(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.i(TAG, "[CALLBACK_GL] boolean onDoubleTap(e:" + e + ")");


        return super.onDoubleTap(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        Log.i(TAG, "[CALLBACK_GL] boolean onFling(e1:" + e1 + ", e2:" + e2 + ", velocityX:" + velocityX
                + ", velocityY:" + velocityY + "");

        final float xDistance = Math.abs(e1.getX() - e2.getX());
        final float yDistance = Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY());

        if(xDistance > this.swipe_Max_Distance || yDistance > this.swipe_Max_Distance)
            return false;

        velocityX = Math.abs(velocityX);
        velocityY = Math.abs(velocityY);
        boolean result = false;

        if(velocityX > this.swipe_Min_Velocity && xDistance > this.swipe_Min_Distance){
            if(e1.getX() > e2.getX()) // right to left
                Log.i(TAG, "Swipe Left");

            else
                Log.i(TAG, "Swipe Right");
        }   

        //return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.i(TAG, "[CALLBACK_GL] void onShowPress(e:" + e + ")");
        super.onShowPress(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.i(TAG, "[CALLBACK_GL] void onLongPress(e:" + e + ")");

        super.onLongPress(e);
    }
};

}
```

An example:
Use this condition in `onFling` for `TopRightToBottomLeft` swipe:

```
// TopRightToBottomLeft
if((e1.getX() > e2.getX()) && (e1.getY() > e2.getY())) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Swipe TopRightToBottomLeft");
}
```

You can try similarly for other events.

Comment: vickey thank you so much for looking into my problem. onFling() it will give the only for rightToLeft, LeftToRight, TopToBottom and BottomToTop. this i did correctly and working fine. problem with calculating the diagonal events. (I need Mathematical calculations to differentiate the diagonal swipe events same as the onFling() functions.)  Once again thank you so much for your replay.

Answer (score 0):

when using GestureDetector you will have to recognize each gesture by yourself, the better solution is to use GestureOverlayView and system app called GestureBuilder that allow to create custom gestures

Comment: Thanks pskink, now i am using GestureDetector only,and calculating the touchDown and touchUp by using them i am calculating the event type.